# I did to hide .php and id on url but css and other styling and js are not showing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried to clean URL using Rewrite Rules in .htaccess it cleans the URL but not showing the styles and other js styles. My .htaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
RewriteRule ^pages/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) pages.php?p_id=$1&p_title=$2 [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Thanks in Advance,

Fahad

Answer (score 0):

This is because your relative URIs have their base changed. Originally, the base is `/` when the page is `/pages.php`, and the browser properly fills in relative links with the `/` base. But when the browser goes to a page like `/pages/1/foo` the base suddenly becomes `/pages/1/foo` and it tries to append that in front of all relative URLs and thus none of them load.

You can either make your links absolute, or change the URI base in the header of your pages (inbetween the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Sorry I don`t understand about absolute links or URL base ?. How should I use the link in my php file. Thanks

Comment: @fhdkaxi absolute links are links with full path ,eg : **<img src="/img/foo.png">** And the relative path to an image looks like **<img src="img/foo.png">** note the leading slash in the absolute  path.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working. I am using all the extensions in my css and javascript file like .css & .js but still it is not showing any styles and scripts.

Comment: @Fhdkaxi did you try adding **<base href="/">** in head of your document?

Comment: the URL is like : http://domain.com/pages/43/title

and the link I am using is : pages/43/title

Comment: Yes I added <base href="/"> but now its only showing images !

Comment: @Fhdkaxi can you check the source code of your webpage to see what base js and css are using in **<link rel** and **<script src="**

Comment: i am using include function in php. I created a file named css.inc.php & javascript.inc.php and I included these files on my header and body section of my page

Comment: <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

& <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

Comment: Try Using absolute paths **<link rel="/style.css**    **<script src="/js**